# A single word that means "mental reaction speed"?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I'm searching for a single-word descriptor that means "mental quickness", "mental reaction speed" or very similar with little additional connotation (unlike alacrity or wits).

**EDIT:** The word has to be able to stand on its own like an icon; I can't rely on context for meaning.  It is an attribute for a table-top role playing game. The character will have a score or rating to represent how mentally quick they are that they will need to call up readily during a game. The word doesn't need to imply that their reactions are correct or accurate, only fast.

**EDIT 2:** The game is set in the mid-near future and is [Post-Cyberpunk](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PostCyberpunk) in nature. Any words that reflect that setting are especially helpful.

Comment: Why do you specifically reject *alacrity* as an undesirable connotation? One of its meanings *is* quickness" . . .

Comment: Alacrity is actually the frontrunner right now. It's the smiling / positivity that gives me slight pause.

Comment: You got something against smiling/positivity? ^_^

Comment: Not for myself, but since it will apply to all characters I don't want anyone to feel like they are forced to act positively because they have a high score in this attribute, only that they are mentally quick (not necessarily accurate or even correct).

Comment: `not necessarily accurate or even correct`?? Quick to be dead wrong is part of your concept?

Comment: How about ***decisiveness***?

Comment: There are many other mental attributes at play: Logic and Intuition would be leveraged to make sure the course of action is correct. This word simply needs to cover mental haste.

Comment: Then I'd opt for "Haste", though that has some negative connotations (and some positive ones).

Comment: Wily - if you want to go to the other end of the spectrum, connotation-wise ;)

Comment: You can always make a word up, right? Or just use "quickness."

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_(role-playing_games)#Common_attribute_names

Comment: Hi please see my answer http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251337/a-single-word-that-means-mental-reaction-speed/252002#252002

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Impulse**

Alternatives: **Synapse, Neuron, Reflex**

Since it's a one word name for a score in a table-top game, I don't think the definition has to mean exactly what the score represents, it just has to be memorable with the player and loosely correlated to the actual definition.

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you! I'll let you know which I go with after I talk to some friends.

Comment: not "impulse," but "impulsiveness."

Comment: @dlibss I would think `implusiveness` implies a negative affect though, meaning perhaps that someone reacts too quickly to be useful. `impulse` sounds like a bonus attribute, `impulsiveness` sounds like a negative one.

Comment: I think Reflex would certainly the most used in common vernacular.

Comment: **Synapse** is what we ended up going with. It fits the setting perfectly and is actually forcing us to go back and re-name the other attributes as well.

Comment: This is ambiguous without a context. Synapse is not a good choice also. I'm not sure why you didn't go with simple clear words. I thought it was your original intent.

Answer (score 56):

**Acuity**

sharpness or keenness of thought, vision or hearing:
*intellectual acuity; visual acuity*

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/acuity);
[Wiktionary](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/acuity)

Comment: This is by far the most accurate word for what the requester is looking for.

Comment: Definitely better than Alacrity, which is what I was going to use. However, Impulse was suggested a few hours later and I plan to go with that instead.

Comment: @Gavin42 - but impulse literally makes no sense here. I have no idea why it was suggested, or why you've accepted it. It's got nothing to do with speed.

Comment: Impulse control is preventing yourself from reacting quickly in a purely mental/emotional way, so Impulse by contrast is nearly perfect. I actually changed it to Synapse this morning, though.

Comment: I love the word, and it beats a lot of the others. However, when I am presented with the word "Acuity" with no context I think of Intelligence, Brilliance, and Keen Senses far before I get to "mental reaction speed", and that is what this question was looking for.

Comment: This is wrong. Sharpness here means in a spatial and not temporal sense. Acuity has to do with ability to resolve two very close but distinct points in space(spectrum). Also in the related fields given in answer vision, acoustics acuity is defined this way. Although impulse is not completely correct, it comes much closer to the answer. This got more votes because impulse is obviously not correct and acuity seems vaguely correct to the voters.

Answer (score 14):

***[Acumen](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/acumen)*** may fit :

> - The ability to make good judgments and quick decisions, typically in a particular domain. (ODO)

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps **Perspicacious**

[Cambridge online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/perspicacious):

> quick in noticing, understanding, or judging things accurately:

Comment: Thanks for teaching me a new word! Sadly, the perception aspect throws the word into too different a realm for me. If I were to use it I'd need to use the form, "Perspicacity".

Answer (score 10):

> **Quick-witted:** *adj.* showing or characterized by an ability to think or respond quickly or effectively.

[Source (Google)](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20quick-witted)

Edit:

After seeing that you want to use it as a measure in a game without context I would suggest *wit*

> **Wit:** *noun*.  mental sharpness and inventiveness; keen intelligence.

[Source (Google)](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20wit)

I also like *resourcefulness*.

> **Resourcefulness**: able to deal skillfully and promptly with new situations, difficulties, etc.

[- Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/resourcefulness)

Comment: I think modern usage of wit is more of a social reaction speed. I wouldn't consider someone witty if they sprouted off a 5 digit by 5 digit multiplication instantly. I would if they had an instant comeback to an insult. Both require "mental sharpness" I suppose, but they manifest in very different ways.

Answer (score 5):

I like Wayfaring Stranger's answer of **perspicacious** (or for a stand-alone noun, **perspicacity**), but for a RPG context, consider this: it might be ok for success to be implied in the trait, only for your players to fail anyway.  Someone with a low agility score, for example, isn't actually very agile; someone with a low charisma isn't charismatic.

The same way, the stand-alone word used for this trait can, out-of-game, mean what will be implied about the character in-game *only if they have a high score* in the trait.

For actual words, I recommend **wit**, **cunning** , or **acumen**, depending on if this will be the basis for glib remarks, on-the-fly explanations, or accurate on-the-spot assessment.

Comment: @Gavin42, which of the answers in this post did you end up going with?

Comment: Not one of the words, specifically. The advice in paragraph one and two made me go back to 'alacrity' with fresh eyes, and I used that. Also, the word I used for physical speed was Celerity, and the two sound great together.

Answer (score 4):

You could use...

**Mental reflexes**

The phrase is almost as common as physical reflexes, according to this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mental%20reflexes%2C%20physical%20reflexes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmental%20reflexes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cphysical%20reflexes%3B%2Cc0).

See [Google books results](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=%22mental%20reflexes%22&tbm=bks)

And [this article](http://counsellingresource.com/features/2013/10/15/sharpen-mental-reflexes/) from counselling resource.

---

**EDIT:** Now that I know your context, try:

[**flair**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flair)

> [IN SINGULAR] A special or instinctive aptitude or ability for doing something well:

Comment: My only admonishment is that I'm looking for a single word. Thanks for the ngram info, though.

Comment: @Gavin42: You could use `reflexes`, and the context could clarify that you're talking about mental reflexes. At the moment, I can't think of a better single-word. And even if you find one, chances are that it will be obscure.

Comment: The word has to be able to stand on its own like an icon. I can't rely on context. Thanks though!

Comment: @Gavin42: I edited your post a bit. Hope you don't mind. Btw, is this about math?

Comment: I don't mind at all. Thank you! No, it is for a table-top role playing game. It is a player character attribute. The character will have a score or rating to represent how mentally quick they are that they will need to call up readily during a game.

Comment: @Gavin42: See edit.

Answer (score 4):

[sagacious](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sagacious) (adj)

> If you comment on something at a deeper level, you are making a
>   **sagacious** observation.
>
> The word is a descendent of [Latin sagus "*prophetic*"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sagacity&allowed_in_frame=0) and is
>   related to the Old English word *seek*.
>
> - "keenness of perception, quality of being acute.
>
> Synonyms include discerning, insightful and another formal word
>   perspicacious.

Comment: I would use "Sagacity", but the problem I have here is the same as with "Perspicacity", steps too far into the realm of perception. I'm a big fan of the word, though :)

Comment: Great word, but in my experience refers to depth and profundity more than quickness.

Comment: This is definitely more along the lines of "knowledge" than "intelligence," which is a classic dichotomy in role-playing games.

Answer (score 3):

I can give you some ideas from a psychological perspective as I teach and research in this area: In psychology when referring to how quickly an individual's cognitive skills operate we use the term ***Processing Speed***. When referring to it by a single word, it's simply ***Processing***.

This refers to the speed with which one thinks, while ***Auditory Processing*** and ***Visual*** **Processing** refer to the perceptual abilities. Other facets of cognition include:

- Logic/Reasoning (Obvious utility, usually incorrectly referred to as intelligence).
- Memory (Working Memory for Processing Speed, LTM for recall of methods, etc.).
- Attention (Sustained, Selective & Divided - three different attributes reflecting an individual's ability to attend to a task in each of these conditions).
- Sequencing (ability to determine which actions make up a complex action such as weaving on a loom.)
- Proprioception (Sense of own body, ability to learn movements through muscle contractions).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

***quick-thinking***:

> Having or showing an ability to think or react quickly and effectively *[[OD]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/quick-thinking)*

Also, you can simply call the ability ***quick-mindedness***.

Comment: Easy to understand so you don't have to rely on the context.

Comment: There is also [repartee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repartee) for quickness in response.

Answer (score 2):

I'll toss "whip-smart" into the ring. It's not fancy, but it definitely gets the point across in a concise and standalone manner, while does not imply any positivity/negativity regarding attitude or personality. Merriam Webster does not recognize it as a word, but several other dictionaries do.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/whip-smart

Answer (score 2):

Choice 1: Quip
Choice 2: Snap

Both these words, being monosyllabic, are crisp.

As you want names for charracters you can make them longer "Quipper" or "Snappy"

Answer (score 2):

**Agility**:

> Agility is the ability to be **quick and graceful**. You might have
>   agility on the basketball court or in the courtroom, or even with your
>   gaming remote. The noun agility can be used for both **mental and
>   physical skills** in speed and grace. Your mental agility might allow
>   you to follow both conversations at once.

**Adroitness**:

> mental/physical cleverness or skill.(For mental skills, you may say 'mental adroitness')

**Sharp-witted**

> (of a person) quick to notice and understand things.

**Shrewd**

> having or showing sharp powers of judgement; **astute**, **acute**.

**Rapier-like wit**

> very quick and accurate or incisive.

**Nimble-witted**

> having or showing an ability to think or respond quickly and effectively.

Other words that are *close to 'mental quickness*': :   razor-sharp, quick, quick-witted, agile, nimble, ingenious, clever, intelligent, bright, brilliant, smart, canny, intuitive, discerning, perceptive, perspicacious, penetrating, insightful, incisive, piercing, discriminating, sagacious, wise, judicious; informal: on the ball, quick off the mark, quick on the uptake, brainy, streetwise, savvy; informal: suss; informal: pawky; informal: heads-up, whip-smart; dated: long-headed; rare: argute, sapient

Answer (score 2):

**Alertness**

*adjective*

1. fully aware and attentive; wide-awake; keen: an alert mind.
2. swift; agile; nimble.

Possibly for your intended use in a role playing game:

**Vigilance**

*noun*

1. state or quality of being vigilant; watchfulness

Where **Vigilant** is defined as:

adjective

1. keenly watchful to detect danger; wary:
   a vigilant sentry.
2. ever awake and alert; sleeplessly watchful.

These both seem to me to avoid problems with the attribute relating to any physical response.

Answer (score 2):

Mentalacrity.

Break the limits of the English syntax.

Comment: Could you please give a definition for this, or have you just made it up?

Answer (score 2):

**Prompt**

Cyber meme - *Your instructions are no match for my command prompt.*

**Swift**

Fast/fluid actions

**Blitz**

Fast chess moves, if you have players.

are some one-word adjectives for mental agility that I use.

Answer (score 0):

Since a slow mental reaction speed is often opposed with intelligence, I propose :

**[brilliant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brilliant)**, which conveys a **light speed** image (nothing is faster than light speed).

> Highly intelligent.

Answer (score 0):

Dexterity is a good choice:

: clever skill : the ability to think and act quickly and cleverly
: the ability to easily move in a way that is graceful
: the ability to use your hands skillfully

Comment: Dexterity refers to adroitness in using the **hands or body** and specifically derives from the word for the **right hand**. I'm looking for something quite different, purely **mental readiness**.

Answer (score 0):

how about the word QUICK, all the above answers imply intellect but not so much speed.

Answer (score 0):

While **perspicacious** highlights the ability the ability of being mentally gifted, it does not offer a sense or an idea of the speed at which such ability is performed.

**Keen** readily comes to mind, so does **sapient** -- "showing quick and ardent responsiveness"
If you're looking for a ready answer to **mental blitz** then you have to create it..

Answer (score 0):

This is two words, but how about [mental chronometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_chronometry)? It's not *exactly* accurate since it seems to refer to the measurement of reaction and cognitive processing speed rather than to mental quickness itself... but it may be close enough for your needs and has a nice cyberpunk feel to it.

You could even just go with "chronometry" for one word -- it seems unlikely to be a source of confusion.

Comment: On the contrary, it would be a source of confusion.  Chronometry is the science of measuring time, not speed.

Comment: @Chenmunka We're not talking here about speed as in physical *velocity*, but rather how much *time* it takes to complete mental tasks. I think the measurement of *durations* of time -- which is all that chronometry can achieve since there isn't really an absolute "value" of time -- is very closely related to that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a single word request. But I had similar problem and settled on the phrase **Presence of Mind** - **POM** for short.

Answer (score -1):

**Cognition**

From the Oxford:

[MASS NOUN]
The mental action or process of acquiring knowledge and understanding through thought, experience, and the senses.